How can I transform two REST responses together in StepZen
I'm using StepZen and I think my use case is pretty simple. I have two independent REST calls into two different backends where each one returns a list.

Call to Backend-A REST endpoint returns ListA
Call to Backend-B REST endpoint returns ListB

So now, I want to get both Lists together to do a transform/operation/ecmascript/whatever... and merge elements. Yes, I need some "code" and I would like to do into GraphQL server.
I don't want two separeted lists like this:
type MergedLists {
    firstList: [FirstList]
    secondList: [SecondList]
}

The final response should be lists merged. So assuming I have this schemas:
type FirstList {
    id: ID!
    value: Int
}

type SecondList {
    id: ID!
    otherValue: Int
}

type Merged {
    firstList: [FirstList] @materializer(query: "getFirstList")
    secondList: [SecondList] @materializer(query: "getSecondList")
}

type Query {

  getFirstList: [FirstList] @rest(endpoint: ".../getFirst_list")
  getSecondList: [SecondList] @rest(endpoint: ".../getSecond_list")
  getMerged: Merged @connector(type: "echo")

}

My idea was to get both lists data into getMerged "stage" and do a transform. I know I can use jq transforms (by the way the command I need is .list1 as $list1 | .list2 as $list2 | $list1 + $list2 | group_by(.id) | map(add)) but I don't know how can I play with the data to use this.
It seems transforms is only available into @rest respones so I can't use here.
So, how can I do a transform on getSecondList using also the response from getFirstList?
Now the response is:
{
  "data": {
    "getMerged": {
      "firstList": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "value": 3
        }
      ],
      "secondList": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "otherValue": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "otherValue": 3
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "otherValue": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

You can see both lists as defined in Merged type. But now is where I want to do a transform and I don't know how.
Thanks in advance.

I've found a workaround to get the desired output, but wondering if there is a better (or at least explained into docs) way.
The trick here is to create and empty @rest endpoint to be able to call transform. And also send elements in a @sequence to be able to get in the last step the previous responses.
To bad part is that I've nedded to use JSON and maybe some types can be missing but I still have types at output so I think it's not that bad.
So the code will be something like this:
type ListResult {
    id: ID!
    value: Int
    otherValue: Int
}

type FirstList {
    firstList: [JSON]
}

type SecondList {
    secondList: [JSON]
}

getMerged: [ListResult] 
    @sequence(
        steps: [
        {query: "getFirstList"}
        {query: "getSecondList"}
        {query: "merge"}
        ]
    )

getFirstList: FirstList @rest(...)
getSecondList: SecondList @rest(...)

# Here the magic is done using an empty endpoint and retrieving firstList and secondList from previous calls in @sequence.
merge(firstList: [JSON], secondList: [JSON]): [ListResult]
@rest(
    endpoint: "stepzen:empty",
    transforms:[{ editor:
    """
        jq:
        get("firstList") as $listA 
        | get("secondList") as $listB
        | ($listA + $listB)
        | group_by(.id)
        | map(add)
        | .[]
    """        
}]
)

I've lost types on firstList and secondList (now is JSON) but I've won the functionality I want and types are still in ListResult... so it's ok for me.
